# Solution to the linear equation 2x + 0y = 0

Tags: linear-algebra

I've resolved that the proposition that x = 0 a solution is true since y has zero as a coefficient.

$$2x + 0y = 0$$
$$2x = 0$$
$$x = 0/2$$
$$x=0$$

Does this imply that x = 0 is the solution to the linear equation 2x + 0y = 0?

Comment: Anything in particular that I need to improve @JoséCarlosSantos?

Comment: Perhaps that you might explain why is it that you are not $100\%$ sure that $2\times0+0\times y=0$. What is your doubt? Besides, the title should **never** be part of the question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I agree to the first part but not to the second. Informative titles are not bad at all, in contrary ! Informative titles are much better than a title like "a problem about matrices"

Comment: @peter Absolutely correct, $0y=0$ is obvious and $2x=0$ clearly implies $x=0$

Comment: @Peter I was just saying that one should be able to understand the question without reading the title. The complete text of the first version of the question consisted only of the sentence “I've resolved that the proposition - that x = 0 - is true because y has zero as a coefficient.”

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I do not find anything wrong with a title that is a part of the question. That might be somewhat redundant but it has advantages such as improving the ability to search the question.

Comment: @Peter As it is written [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/446262), “The title is not the first sentence of your question”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is indeed the solution. We can divide both sides of the equation by 2 to obtain $x+0y=x=0$, since $0/2=0$. However, note that this gives infinitely many solutions $(x, y)$, since we can enter any value for $y$, as long as $x=0$. The following are all solutions for example: $(0, 3), (0,-5), (0,0)$.